# How to make list in div tag inline in pug

Tags: html, pug

How can i make this div inline in pug

```
div(class='lastfooter')
  ul
    li
      a(href="#") Advertising
    li
      a(href="#") Business
    li
      a(href="#") About 
    li
      a(href="#") How search works
  ul.privacy
    li  
      a(href="#") Privacy
    li  
      a(href="#") Terms
    li  
      a(href="#") Settings
```

How can i make this div tag inline in pug and also how to make use of loop in list with href

```
-
    var list = ["Advertising", "Buisness", "About","How search works"]
  each item in list
    li= a(href="#")item
```

This code returns error in loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you.

```
-
  var list = ["Advertising", "Buisness", "About","How search works"]
div(class='lastfooter')
  ul
    each item in list
      li!= '<a href="#">'+item+'</a>'
```